# How do I make RelativeLayout disappear when scrolling in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

I've included a header **RelativeLayout** inside another **RelativeLayout** that contains the **RecyclerView**. I want the header to scroll with the **RecyclerView**, that is, as I scroll down the RecyclerView, the header will disappear and will only reappear at the very top.

[This](https://paste.ofcode.org/UG3YgEzEQ7Hkx6Cq3uyx57) is the Activity layout (which includes both the **RecyclerView** and the header). [This](https://paste.ofcode.org/FXFGubd4PTkwbZ8qsrLXZS) is the XML file for the header. [This](https://paste.ofcode.org/jmsHLSufCrCaQhyjyfNjEc) is the android **Activity**.

Comment: Why don't you add the header inside `RecyclerView` Itself ?

Comment: @NileshDeokar I don't think that's possible. The header alone is composed of an ImageView, a TextView, and a LinearLayout.

Comment: What difference will it make ? All you need to do is inflate `header_view` if position is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing you should add header inside top of recycler view ,you can refer this link to implement header in recycler view

https://github.com/lopspower/HFRecyclerView

It's help me to add header at top of recycler view.